# Cross platform (de)serialization of char* from file

Tags: c, cross-platform, fwrite, fread

I need to `fwrite`a `char *` to file and `fread` it on another platform where `char`'s signedness varies.

- Are there ways to solve this *other* than explicitly serializing a `unsigned char*`?
- Is it always safe to cast a `char*` to an `unsigned char*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, it's safe to access **any type** as `unsigned char [sizeof T]`; this is called the *representation*. The question is whether copying this representation between diverse systems will preserve the *value*. Here are the relevant facts/issues:

- All positive values of `char` (and keep in mind, all characters in the basic execution character set must be positive) have the same representation as an `unsigned char` with the same value. (The same applies to other signed/unsigned integer types too.)
- On a twos-complement system, signed and unsigned `char` types are completely compatible (modulo the difference in how the values are interpreted) and it's perfectly safe to access them as either type. Moreover, the C standard makes it difficult if not impossible to produce a valid implementation where plain `char` is signed and not twos-complement, and I think it's safe to say no such implementation exists or will ever exist.
- Even if the *values* as `char` (these are integers!) are preserved when transporting the file to another system, that doesn't necessarily imply that the character identities will be preserved, since the target system might use a different character encoding (EBCDIC puke..).

This is a lot of mumbo-jumbo, but the result you should take away is that unless your goal is pedantry and language-lawyering, there's nothing to worry about. Just use `fwrite` and `fread` directly on strings and don't worry about whether they were `unsigned char[]` or `char[]` strings.

Answer (score 4):

Those two platforms must agree to some extent on the representation of `char`, in order for you to have transferred the file from one to the other.

So there's no "completely portable" way to do this - for example suppose `char` is 16 bits on the platform that writes, and 8 bits on the platform that reads, then clearly you can't in general transfer chars from one to the other. Either it's impossible to do it at all (16 bit char suggest a DSP, it might have no file- or stream-based I/O), or there's some agreed rule how to convert the file when transferring it.

There also needs to be either agreement what the execution character set is, or else a means of converting the file between (for example) EBCDIC and ASCII. Otherwise writing an `a` on one side won't result in reading an `a` on the other.

Once you've established the rules for how closely `char` corresponds on each side, that tells you what you can read and write. If the *only* difference is that the signedness of `char` varies, but they both use the same character set, then just check how the one that's signed represents negative values.

Assuming it does so in the only common way (two's complement), and supposing that both sides convert from unsigned to signed integers in the only common way (re-interpret the bit pattern), then you can just read and write `char` normally on both sides with effectively the same results as casting between `unsigned char` and `signed char`.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks for the interesting tidbit about DSPs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are 'serializing' char's without negative ones, then it doesn't matter. Otherwise it doesn't make sense (since you won't be able to determine which value was written).